# Prediction for pretrained model on handwritten text(images)-Pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, encoder-decoder

I have a problem making a prediction using a pre-trained model that contains an encoder and decoder for handwritten text recognition.
What I did is the following:

```
checkpoint = torch.load("Model/SPAN/SPAN-PT-RA_rimes.pt",map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
encoder_state_dict = checkpoint['encoder_state_dict']
decoder_state_dict = checkpoint['decoder_state_dict']

img = torch.LongTensor(img).unsqueeze(1).to(torch.device('cpu'))
global_pred = decoder_state_dict(encoder_state_dict(img))
```

This generates this error:

```
TypeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object is not callable
```

I would highly appreciate your help! ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `encoder_state_dict` and `decoder_state_dict` are not Torch models themselves, but rather some structure like dictionaries containing tensors. These tensors represent the pre-trained parameters of the checkpoint you have loaded.

It's not logical to directly feed inputs (like your transformed input image) to these collections of tensors. Instead, you should load these `state_dicts` — essentially collections of pre-trained tensors — into the parameters of your model object. This model should be structured according to the network you're working with, as defined in the [`torch.nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html) class.

Comment: What I did is the following: `encoder=FCN_Encoder()
encoder.load_state_dict(SPAN['encoder_state_dict'])
encoder.eval()
decoder=Decoder()
decoder.load_state_dict(SPAN['decoder_state_dict'])
decoder.eval()
features = encoder(image)
output = decoder(features)
output ` and I got a tensor as output. If I get it right this is my predicted output but It should be transformed to a paragraph (the prediction) and This is where I am stuck. If you have an idea about this please help me.

Comment: I would guess you're trying to generate a paragraph per image (like image captioning?). If that's the case and if the decoder does its thing, then the output from the decoder should contain ids, each of which is mapped to a vocabulary. You can convert those ids altogether into vocab strings. Although the `decoder` class is much abstract now as you've not provided the code for it, this is a generally-done approach in enc-dec frameworks.